# Multiple iterators in php

Tags: php, iteration

I have the following code. Basically, for each question if the answer's "question_id" matches the question's id I need it to list all of the possible answers for the question. It does this for the first question, but then exits the loop.

```
            <?php foreach ($questions as $question) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $question['question']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $question['id']; ?></td>
            </tr>
                <?php foreach ($answers as $answer) : ?>
                <?php if ($answer['question_id'] == $question['id']) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $answer['answer']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
```

How can I continue to iterate through the rest of the $question['id'] values?

Comment: can you add what's inside `$questions`?

Comment: It is an array of question objects, which have id, question(the actual string question) and survey_id, which is the id of the survey that they belong to. $answers is the array of answer objects (id, answer, question_id).

Comment: looks right to me, would nned an example of each array to test it

Comment: Looks fine logically. It's possible you aren't getting the correct data inside the variables as you are expecting. Run [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) on $questions and $answers to see if you see them contain all the data you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically because you are missing the closing semicolon

```
<?php endforeach ?> // <-- here
```

That should give you a fatal error if you properly setup the [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).